# PHP Twitter bot using AIML engine and Mysql database as backend

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, bots

this is my first question and i'm also quite new to this site.

I am developing a twitter bot as final year project and as working environment i am on windows 7 64 as operating system and have server 2go with PHP 5.3 version, MySql and AIML engine program E up and running properly. I registered the application on twitter developers section of the site with read and write access. This is intended to be a client application (not web) but couldn't see that option to choose while registering on the developers' section of the site. I wonder what would be the best Ouath library to access the twitter REST Api? I found on a forum that a a PIN based Oauth prevents HTTP access to the bot control...
Unfortunately there are only php tutorials for developing this on linux and fedora but it's more convenient to use windows and PHP as the AI engine i use and the backend database are written in PHP.

Hope the above is clear and i really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: No, the above wasn't clear, but I think you want a simple OAuth library that doesn't force you to use a PIN :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [@Abraham's TwitterOAuth library.](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

On [Twitter's dev portal](https://dev.twitter.com), you'll find not only the consumer keys but also the keys to your bot's account. You will then have one consumer token, one consumer secret, one user token, one user secret.

With the TwitterOAuth library, you can simply use one simple constructor that does all this for you.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET);
```

Once you have the connection set up, you can simply post a tweet:

```
$connection -> post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'First tweet from PHP!'));
```

And that's all :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's working. And how do i read and respond automatically to direct messages?